# What are the elements with the minimal absolute values in cyclotomic extensions of the integer ring?

Tags: number-theory

We can easily see 1 has the (nonzero) minimal absolute value in the integer ring. In the Gaussian integer ring and the Eisenstein integer ring, 1 is also the minimal (complex) absolute value. However, I saw an example of element a with $0 <|a|<1$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\xi_8] $. Then, is there a general formula of the minimal abs of $\mathbb{Z}[\xi_n] $ for each $n $? What are the minimal abs elements?

Comment: The number $|a|$ is *not* a norm. Algebraic integers have norms in $\mathbf Z$ so the minimal nonzero norm in absolute value is $1$, which is the norm of $1$.

Comment: Hmm, so I use the expression "(complex) norm". Although | | is not a norm in the ring, I guess we can say about the minimal absolute value in the rings..

Comment: If you're using "norm" to mean "modulus", then I think you'll find that in any cyclotomic extension of degree exceeding 2, the algebraic integers are dense in the complex numbers, so there are integers of arbitrarliy small modulus.

Comment: Thanks! I need to study more...